# Dynamic JSF UI Components Generation

Tags: java, xml, jsf, dynamic

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let's say that I have a settings.xml file that looks as follows:

```
<SETTINGS>
   <username fieldType="TextField" possibleValues="*">username_value</username>
   <roletype fieldType="DropDownList" possibleValues="normal,admin,agent">admin</roletype>
   <active fieldType="RadioButtons" possibleValues="true,false">true</active>
<SETTINGS>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:
1- When my page first loads, it will parse this xml file, and layout the UI components based on the fieldType and the possibleValues.
2- When my UI components are loaded, I should be able to configure the value of my fields, which will end up persisting in my settings.xml file.

Is there a ready library that does this? Or do I need to write the code for this myself?

***Note: I'm restricted to using JSF 1.x***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , i will recommend to change the structure of your XML file as:

```
<SETTINGS>
<controls>
<control label="username" fieldType="TextField">
    <values></values>
    <selvalue></selvalue>
</control>

<control label="roletype" fieldType="DropDownList">
    <values>
       <value>normal</value>
       <value>admin</value>
       <value>agent</value>
    </values>
    <selvalue></selvalue>
</control>

<control label="active" fieldType="RadioButtons">
 <values>
   <value>true</value>
   <value>false</value>    
 </values>
    <selvalue></selvalue>
</control>
```

Now use `JAXB` to parase this XML file to the different classed, where each xml tab will be act as one independent class.
like :

Settings :

```
 private List<Control> controls;
```

Control :

```
  String label; // Attribute
  String fieldType; // Attribute
  Values values; //Property
  String selValue; //Property
```

Values :

```
 List<Value> values; ////Property
```

Value :

```
String value; //Property
```

DynaCritSearchBean : A Bean Class

```
Settings settings;
```

Once the data is loaded in to the corresponding class, use the following logic to dynamically create the screen in your XHTML file :

```
<h:panelGrid>
 <c:forEach var="control" 
    items="#{dynaCritSearchBean.settings.controls}">
  <h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText value="#{control.label}" />
  </h:panelGroup>

  <h:panelGroup>
        <c:choose>
          <c:when test="#{control.fieldType eq 'TextField'}">
            <h:inputText value="#{control.selvalue}" />
          </c:when>

          <c:when test="#{control.fieldType eq 'DropDownList'}">
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{control.selvalue}">
              <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="--select--" />
                <c:forEach var="selOneValue" items="#{control.values.values}">
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{selOneValue}" 
                                itemLabel="#{selOneValue}" />
                 </c:forEach>
             </h:selectOneMenu>         
          </c:when>

          <!-- Same as above logic for Radio button -->

        </c:choose>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </c:forEach>
  </h:panelGrid>
```

Once you submit the form, all selected/entered values are set to corresponding `selValue` of each Control.

Now, in order to get the XML back, you can use same `JAXB` concept which is very simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer Nirdesh. One thing I couldn't understand in what you said is the following: "Now, in order to get the XML back, you can use same JAXB concept which is very simple."

Could you please tell me how to do that exactly?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The concept of converting Objects into XML file is known as Marshalling . You can see the following links for the simple example.  http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/